# Can a C++ vector of non-pointer types cause a memory leak in iOS?

Tags: ios, memory-leaks, objective-c++, stdvector

Here's the code:

```
@interface myClass {
  std::vector<float> myVector 
}
@end
```

It's leaking according to instruments. Here's the stack trace:

```
1 libstdc++.6.dylib operator new(unsigned long)  
2 __gnu_cxx::new_allocator<float>::allocate(unsigned long, void const*)  
3 std::_Vector_base<float, std::allocator<float> >::_M_allocate(unsigned long)
```

I'm guessing I should be allocating the vector on the heap, but I still don't understand why this occurs. It's also possible I'm failing to dealloc the class properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check if your class's dealloc is called. It seems to be the one way that can call leak in this case. And just one question: why don't you use native objective-c containers? You well need to store your floats in NSNumbers, but you will be able to use standard retain/release memory management model for all of your instances.

Comment: I was able to get the class to dealloc somehow (oh so many problems), and the leak is gone.  

I used vectors because I call a bunch of C++ code which I didn't feel like rewriting. I don't yet know the bad consequences of using C++ for iOS programming either. Oh so much to learn. Thanks for the NSNumber info though!

Comment: you can use c++ for iOS freely, but objective-c has much more comfortable model of memory management

Comment: Ah okay, nice to know. I've heard bad things happen when you mix Obj-C C++ on iOS. I'll know soon enough.