# Memory leak from vector of vectors in iOS

Tags: c++, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks, vector

I'm getting a memory leak in iOS when I use a vector of vectors of floats in a C++ object.

In my object's declaration:

```
class object {
    // ...
    vector< vector < float > > m_vBuffers;
}
```

and in the constructor:

```
m_vBuffers.resize( uNumBuffers );
for( uint iBuf= 0; iBuf < uNumBuffers; ++iBuf )
    m_vBuffers[iBuf].resize( uMaxLength );
```

Now, instruments shows me a leak in the constructor on the resize operation. How can I fix this?
(Also, I thought vectors of vectors of non-pointers didn't have to be explicitly deleted? Is that wrong?)

Comment: I don't think, this is posssible. Also, "leak in the **constructor on the resize" ? `resize` is function, does not have constructor.

Comment: @KirilKirov Guess what he meant was that one of his classes makes calls to `resize` in the class' constructor.

Comment: You are not allocating any heap memory - there can be no leak unless there is a leak in the vector implementation.

Comment: @RageD How do you know it's not heap memory? `m_vBuffers` is a member, so it's allocated in the same memory where the container class is stored.

Comment: @Luke did you check that the destructor is properly called? I don't see any other way here to have a memory leak. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869238) sounds very similar to yours.

Comment: @EitanT: Memory allocated on the heap requires a `new` call (in general, the stack grows down and heap grows up since technically they are all on the same memory). That said, in this excerpt of code, there are no `new` calls, he simply created an object on the stack. Unless iOS does things painfully differently than a standard OS.

Comment: @RageD If the class itself is allocated on the heap, all of its members will be allocated on the heap as well. You don't know how the OP allocates the **class**, so you don't know where its members are stored.

Comment: @Luke Add some `NSLog`s to the destructor of your class to check whether it's called or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this was in fact a problem with the destruction of my object, not of the vector. I wasn't thinking about the Instruments stack trace properly.